# Simple range and domain function on ti-nspire cx cas not working

Tags: ti-nspire

I am trying to code a simple function in the program editior of ti nspire cas cx.

```
Define LibPub transsolabcd()=
Prgm
:Request "Enter original expression: ",expr1,0
:Request "Enter mapped expression: ",expr2,0
:Request "Enter respect var: ",xvar,0
:Local a,b,c,d
:Define exprf1(xvar)=Func
:  Return expr1
:EndFunc
:Define exprf2(xvar)=Func
:  Return expr2
:EndFunc
:Disp (exprf1(2))
:EndPrgm
```

`Disp (exprf1(2))` - This line here does not substitute for the value entered into the function, instead returns the entire function that was requested earlier. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming `xvar` is `x`):

```
Define LibPub transsolabcd()=
Prgm
:Request "Enter original expression: ",expr1,0
:Request "Enter mapped expression: ",expr2,0
:Request "Enter respect var: ",xvar,0
:Local a,b,c,d
:Define exprf1(xvar)=Func
:  Return expr1|x=xvar
:EndFunc
:Define exprf2(xvar)=Func
:  Return expr2|x=xvar
:EndFunc
:Disp (exprf1(2))
:EndPrgm
```

The part I added, `|x=xvar`, substitutes `x` with the value of `xvar`, which is `2` in your function call.